Is OPT a "passport or national identity card" for ESTA purposes?
Filling in the ESTA application, I was asked this question: "Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?"
If I was approved for OPT once, is the answer yes or no?

Seriously,  what is an OPT? What country issues it and what for?

@DJClayworth OPT is "optional practical training" in the US, it allows an individual on a student visa to work for a limited time after their degree


"Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?"
If I was approved for OPT once, is the answer yes or no?

If the issued card looks similar to the image below, then no.
The card states: Not valid for reentry to U.S., thus is not intended for travel.
It is also not a national identity card, which should be understood as a id card issued by a country to its own nationals.


Sources:

Optional Practical Training (OPT) for F-1 Students | USCIS

